# Mongodb default with current timestamp on insert

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Is it possible to have a field with a default value as a current timestamp on insert? It's possible to do this with an update:

```
self.db.history.insert(activity, { '$current_date': { 'timestamp': { '$type': 'timestamp' } } })
```

But [$current_date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) only works for update.

Maybe I should just create a timestamp in Python since a few milliseconds or seconds won't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert document with current date in MongoDB  using `pymongo`, import [**`datetime.datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)  from the standard library.

```
from datetime import datetime

collection.insert({ "created_date": datetime.now() }
```